# css flex - The third column is shown below the second column

Tags: css

I used flex for layout and found strange problems
 When the window is reduced by 800, the third module should be under the second module

[image: desktop view]

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.left {
  width: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

.center {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 900px;
  flex-shrink: 2;
  background: red;
}

.right {
  width: 140px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    center
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

the window 800px , I want this：

[image: desired mobile view]

```
    <style>
        @media screen and (max-width:800px){
           .right{
             ....
           }
        }
    </style>
```

Please help me with this~
  I don't know how it works

Comment: Are you allowed to change the grid (HTML)?

Comment: You should read more on css flex: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
From what i see you might need to use float instead of flex. And at 800px add min-width in percentage to the columns to as to fit into the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `float` for this, nor do you need to change your HTML.

You `can` do this via CSS alone, you can change the direction of your flexbox to column instead of row.

But personally I would consider maybe using grid view here for the main layout. It's cleaner and makes setting up the areas much easier.

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.left {
  width: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

.center {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 900px;
  flex-shrink: 2;
  background: red;
}

.right {
  width: 140px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .flex-box {
    flex-flow: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .left {
   height: 100%;
  }
  
  .center,
  .right{
    height: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    center
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```